# How do I truncate long document for bert?

Tags: nlp

I am trying some bert tutorial in my language, document(korean, non-latin)
however, document is very long. so i have to truncate it. and I dont know how.
if there is a text(ex: 5, "I have a brown cat") longer than max_length(for ex:3), then which one is the right truncation do i have to make? (dont think about start/end word/mask)
a: [("I have a"), ("brown cat [pad]")] or  b:[("I have a"), ("have a brown"), ("a brown cat")]
which one should be better?
or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the notion is, you have to do the truncation before prepending and appending the `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` tokens. And you can indeed choose the number MAX tokens of 512, for BERT-base model alone. So, the idea is, first you choose the MAX tokens less than 512 (If you are using BERT-base). Then, split the sentence to its list of word-pieces, then truncate the sentence to `MAX_tokens - 2`. With this, when you add `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` tokens, it would have a number of tokens equal to `MAX_tokens`. For any sentence having the number of tokens (including `[CLS]` and `[SEP]`) less than MAX_tokens, you can always append with zeros.

Comment: thanks for some tips. but actualy, i was asking about truncating method, not about start/end/pad word(sorry for wrong example). can you give me an example of truncation? or your opinion about method a and b?

Comment: For most of the examples, you generally truncate the last part of the sentence exceeding the max length.

Comment: N the example a or b doesn't make much sense, because you are repeating the parts of sentences.

Comment: I see. then how do I know that truncated sentence(in case above, "I have a") can represent full sentence? It confuses me that "I have a" can be equal to "I have a brown cat"

Comment: You have to pick quite long sentence (you can use upto 512 tokens in a sentence). In very long sentence, it's a tradeoff, you need to choose what suits better for you. Alternatively there are models such as transformer-XL, which can take into account the long sequence lengths.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have

```
list(map(lambda t: ['[CLS]'] + tokenizer.tokenize(t)[:511] + ['[SEP]'], train_texts))
```

or

```
list(map(lambda t: ['[CLS]'] + tokenizer.tokenize(t)[-510:] + ['[SEP]'], train_texts))
```

In the encoder.